# Probability problem based on Catalan number

Tags: probability, permutations, catalan-numbers

I was trying to solve the following problem:

> $n$ boys and $n-1$ girls stand in a queue. The probability that the
> number of boys ahead of every girl is at least one more than the number
> of girls ahead of her is

This does resemble the types of problems of $n$ open braces, and $n$ closing braces solved using Catalan's number. However, I was not able to convert this into the same idea since here $n-1$ girls are present instead of $n$. And, I fear that if I calculate the permutations based on $n$ girls instead of $n-1$ the answer might turn to be different. So I'm not able to prove if they are equal. How should I proceed?

Comment: Hint: $n$ and $n-1$ are coprime, allowing a completely different and much more straightforward solution.

Comment: Consider the $2n-1$ different cyclic permutations (i.e. place the people in a circle, and cut that circle at different points to get different queues). Only one of them is valid. Why?

Comment: Consider BBGGB, as a cyclic permutation, when cut at different points will give. BBGGB, BGGBB, GGBBB, GBBBG, BBBGG out of these BBGGB, BBBGG are both valid ?

Comment: Ah, I silently assumed that every boy has the same condition.